# Ajusting date column (Fill the Date Gaps and update until specific date)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dask

I have the following situation:

A dataframe that shows every inventory movements (Buy/Sell) of each products and store.

```
        date     sku     store  Units   balance
0 2019-10-01  103993.0    001    0.0     10.0
1 2019-10-02  103993.0    001    1.0      9.0
2 2019-10-04  103993.0    001    1.0      8.0
3 2019-10-05  103993.0    001    0.0      8.0
4 2019-10-01  103994.0    002    0.0     12.0
5 2019-10-02  103994.0    002    1.0     11.0
6 2019-10-04  103994.0    002    1.0     10.0
7 2019-10-05  103994.0    002    0.0     10.0
```

Supposing today is 2019-10-08, what is the best way to update this date:

- Filling the gaps (eg. adding 2019-01-03 row)
- Update every (sku and Store) to today's date:

  - Keeping Store and Balance column with the last value
  - Insert 0 to Units columns (which means during these days, I didn't have units sold)

So the output should be like this:

```
           date     sku     store  Units   balance
    0 2019-10-01  103993.0    001    0.0     10.0
    1 2019-10-02  103993.0    001    1.0      9.0
    2 2019-10-03  103993.0    001    0.0      9.0
    3 2019-10-04  103993.0    001    1.0      8.0
    4 2019-10-05  103993.0    001    0.0      8.0
    5 2019-10-06  103993.0    001    0.0      8.0
    6 2019-10-07  103993.0    001    0.0      8.0
    7 2019-10-08  103993.0    001    0.0      8.0
    8 2019-10-01  103994.0    002    0.0     12.0
    9 2019-10-02  103994.0    002    1.0     11.0
   10 2019-10-03  103994.0    002    0.0     11.0
   11 2019-10-04  103994.0    002    1.0     10.0
   12 2019-10-05  103994.0    002    0.0     10.0
   13 2019-10-06  103994.0    002    0.0     10.0
   14 2019-10-07  103994.0    002    0.0     10.0
   15 2019-10-08  103994.0    002    0.0     10.0
```

The only way I found to do this is:

```
    dfs = []
    for _, d in df.groupby(['sku', 'store']):

        start_date = d.date.iloc[0]
        end_date = pd.Timestamp('2019-10-08')

        d.set_index('date', inplace=True)
        d = d.reindex(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date))
        dfs.append(d)

    df = pd.concat(dfs)
    df[['units']] = df[['units']].fillna(0)
    df.ffill(inplace=True)
```

However this code is not well vectorized. Is there a better way to get the same result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
# min date
min_date = df.date.min()

# create a new index
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.sku.unique(),
                                      pd.date_range(min_date, '2019-10-08', freq='D')),
                                     names=['sku','date']
                                    )

# reindex
new_df = df.set_index(['sku','date']).reindex(new_idx)

# fillna
new_df.Units = new_df.Units.fillna(0)

# ffill by group and dropna for invalid dates
new_df = new_df.groupby(level=0).ffill().dropna()
```

Output:

```
                     store  Units  balance
sku      date                             
103993.0 2019-09-30    1.0    0.0     10.0
         2019-10-01    1.0    0.0     10.0
         2019-10-02    1.0    1.0      9.0
         2019-10-03    1.0    0.0      9.0
         2019-10-04    1.0    1.0      8.0
         2019-10-05    1.0    0.0      8.0
         2019-10-06    1.0    0.0      8.0
         2019-10-07    1.0    0.0      8.0
         2019-10-08    1.0    0.0      8.0
103994.0 2019-10-01    2.0    0.0     12.0
         2019-10-02    2.0    1.0     11.0
         2019-10-03    2.0    0.0     11.0
         2019-10-04    2.0    1.0     10.0
         2019-10-05    2.0    0.0     10.0
         2019-10-06    2.0    0.0     10.0
         2019-10-07    2.0    0.0     10.0
         2019-10-08    2.0    0.0     10.0
```

**Note:** this approach can be expensive if the min date for different sku are very different and far from today.

Comment: Hi @Quang Hoang, thanks for your answer. I need to perform this taking into consideration both ['sku', 'store'] as a group.

Comment: Is the minimum date the same for all `sku`? I guess not.

Comment: No, only the end date will be the same.